# Рисование примитивов с использованием windows.h

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Раньше на borland c++ рисовал примитивы через `graphics.h`. Вычитал что в MSVS есть то же самое только это все происходит через `windows.h`. Ищу информацию по поводу рисования примитивов. А также можно ли реализовать данную вещь:

Есть два двумерных массива. в одном точки - просто рисование точки. В другом координаты точек которые связаны линиями между собой линиями.

Comment: [Windows GDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы вам посоветовал использовать сразу специализированные инструменты для таких целей. Например, подключить *OpenGL* к проекту и рисовать с его помощью всё, что угодно.

Comment: OpenGL не лучшее решение, если речь идет о паре сотен точек и линий.

Comment: Я не большой специалист в этом деле. CPaintDC?